# Show the existence of a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

We know that $f_y:=\partial f/\partial y$ exists in an open set containing the origin, where $f$ is a real-valued function defined in this set.Does the following limit exist?
 $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f_y(h,0)-f_y(0,0)}{h}$$

My thought is that since $f_y$ is defined in the open set containing the origin, then $f_y(h,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ should both exist, but I'm not sure if there's a precise way of showing the existence of such limit. Could someone provide a short proof please? Thanks.

Comment: If $h$ is fixed, how can $h\to0$?

Comment: Sorry, I copied it wrong from the question, just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit does not exist in general. If it did, it limit would be the first derivative with respect to $x$ of $f_y$ at $(0,0)$. As a counterexample you can take for instance
$$
f(x,y)=|x|\,y,\quad f_y(x,y)=|x|.
$$

Comment: So if the limit do exist, this limit would equal to $f_{yx}$ by definition?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my answer, which was incorrect.